# Best secure options for passing basic authentication to SOAP API from within a managed package

Tags: soap-api

What are the most secure options of sending user/pwd to SOAP API from within a managed package?

I know that we could use protected custom settings to hide the credentials from the subscriber org.

Even though the purpose of custom metadata is different, is this an option too?

Comment: You will not pass security review if you attempt to store username and passwords (and they catch it) regardless of where you store them. You should be using oAuth and storing the tokens anyway

Answer (score 0):

I have to think [`Named Credential`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm) would be the most secure.

> ## [Named Credentials as Callout Endpoints](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_named_credentials.htm)
>
> A named credential specifies the URL of a callout endpoint and its required authentication parameters in one definition. Salesforce manages all authentication for Apex callouts that specify a named credential as the callout endpoint so that your code doesn’t have to. You can also skip remote site settings, which are otherwise required for callouts to external sites, for the site defined in the named credential.
>   By separating the endpoint URL and authentication from the callout definition, named credentials make callouts easier to maintain. For example, if an endpoint URL changes, you update only the named credential. All callouts that reference the named credential simply continue to work.
>
> If you have multiple orgs, you can create a named credential with the same name but with a different endpoint URL in each org. You can then package and deploy—on all the orgs—one callout definition that references the shared name of those named credentials. For example, the named credential in each org can have a different endpoint URL to accommodate differences in development and production environments. If an Apex callout specifies the shared name of those named credentials, the Apex class that defines the callout can be packaged and deployed on all those orgs without programmatically checking the environment.
>
> To reference a named credential from a callout definition, use the named credential URL. A named credential URL contains the scheme callout:, the name of the named credential, and an optional path. For example: callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path.
>
> You can append a query string to a named credential URL. Use a question mark (?) as the separator between the named credential URL and the query string. For example: callout:My_Named_Credential/some_path?format=json.
>
> ## Example
>
> In the following Apex code, a named credential and an appended path specify the callout’s endpoint.
>
> ```
> HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
> req.setEndpoint('callout:***My_Named_Credential***/some_path');
> req.setMethod('GET');
> Http http = new Http();
> HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
> System.debug(res.getBody());
> ```
>
> The referenced named credential specifies the endpoint URL and the authentication settings.
>
> [image: Named credential detail page]

Comment: I know that OAuth and Named Credentials are options too, but I am trying to understand all the available options to pass the credentials to SOAP API in a secure way. Rephrasing my question, if the Client were to pass username/password to the managed package, would custom metadatatype be an option? Also, what about encrypted text?

Comment: This is the problem with asking for the "best" option to do any particular thing...that's basically a completely different question from your title.

Comment: Sorry @Adrian, my last question is definetely different from my title. I want to know all the solutions so that it's easy to understand why the best solution is the best. Any link or documentation of relevance would be highly appreciated.